# Changing the timestamp of a symlink

Tags: rhel, symlink, timestamps

I know how to change the timestamp of a regular file:

```
touch -t 201301291810 myfile.txt
```

I was not able to do the same with a symlink.  Is it possible?

Distro:  RHEL 5.8

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: i need to alter a timestamp so the symlink looks like it was created in the past

Comment: But why....what more global problem are you trying to address?  Is this just asthetics, or does it have a real purpose?

Comment: that is irrelevant.  i am not going into my business logic

Comment: This type of information helps us all to get to a solution that would work for you.  Its not irreleveant.  Sorry you are so sensitive, I'm just trying to help.

Comment: dude, it is irrelevant.  just go with the need for changing the timestamp as a given constant, invariable.  you can question it all you want but it is not changing on my end.  which makes the questioning pretty much useless, effectively.  good luck

Comment: @mdpc, I have the same problem, I want to tune the order, which torrents are listed in my Transmission GUI.

Answer (score 66):

add switch -h

```
touch -h -t 201301291810 myfile.txt

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a                     change only the access time
  -c, --no-create        do not create any files
  -d, --date=STRING      parse STRING and use it instead of current time
  -f                     (ignored)
  -h, --no-dereference   affect each symbolic link instead of any referenced
                         file (useful only on systems that can change the
                         timestamps of a symlink)
  -m                     change only the modification time
  -r, --reference=FILE   use this file's times instead of current time
  -t STAMP               use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

Comment: > touch -h -t 201301291810 mysymlink -> touch: invalid option -- h
Try `touch --help' for more information.

Comment: look at the quote "useful only on systems that can change the timestamps of a symlink".

Comment: It was also only added recently (it's not in [this manpage from 2010](http://man.he.net/?topic=touch&section=1)). Maybe he needs to just get the latest version of coreutils. [Here's the diff of when it was added in 2009](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=9e13b6a0b41532b63778aa67df40710df41174eb)

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please mark it as such.

Comment: @qodeninja After over six years, I don't really expect the OP to mark it one way or the other.

Comment: Note that for `touch` to support `-h` the system must also implement the actual C method `lutimes()`. Not all systems support this.

Comment: Confirmed works on OSX 10.15.7

Answer (score 4):

You may need a more recent version of `touch`. If this is not an option, and if you know C, you could write a small program to do it yourself using the [lutimes function](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/lutimes.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

A brute force way is as follows:

```
 0. delete the old symlink you wish to change     
 1. change the system date to whatever date you want the symlink to be
 2. remake the symlink
 3. return the system date to current.
```

Comment: made me curious, what system requires this? btw, any file created while you have not yet fixed the sytem date will have that timestamp too

Comment: Because one is unable to modify the symlink inode once created.

Comment: @mdpc See `lutimes()`.

Answer (score 1):

The atime and mtime of a symbolic link can be changed using the `lutimes` function.  The following program works for me on MacOSX and Linux to copy both times from an arbitrary file to a symbolic link:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct timeval times[2];
    struct stat info;
    int rc;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s source target\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    rc = lstat(argv[1], &info);
    if (rc != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot stat %s, %s\n", argv[1],
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    times[0].tv_sec = info.st_atime;
    times[0].tv_usec = 0;
    times[1].tv_sec = info.st_mtime;
    times[1].tv_usec = 0;
    rc = lutimes(argv[2], times);
    if (rc != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot set times on %s, %s\n", argv[2],
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you call the compiled file `copytime`, then the command `copytime file link` can be used to make link have the same atime and mtime as `file` does.  It shouldn't be too difficult to modify the program to use times specified on the command line instead of copying the times from another file.