# How to check the timestamp of a symbolic link?

Tags: symlink, timestamps

Is there a way to use traditional commands to update a symlink when it's older than the original file?

I use a Seafile server (similar to Dropbox) to make certain files available to my students. So I shared a directory and created links to those files. Both Seafile and Dropbox don't care about links and copy the actual files to the server.

The problem is that if I update the actual file, the link timestamp doesn't change and the new version of the file is not uploaded to the server.

I tried the trivial test:

```
[ ./shared/the-symlink -ot ./actualfiles/pontedfile ] && touch -h ./shared/the-symlink
```

Unfortunately, `test` dereferences the link and the timestamp of the file is compared to itself, what results false, of course.

Note also that the symlink must be newer than the linked file. I don't need it to be set to the same timestamp.

Is there a way to `test` check the timestamp of the link instead of the pointed file?

Other solutions I'm trying to avoid:

- Copying the files instead of linking would work, but I'd have to consume too much disk space because the files are usually large;
- `touch`ing all symlinks would also works, but all the files would be copyied to the server again and again; (**not a problem**: see edit below)

I'm willing a more elegant solution than converting the timestamps to string and comparing them by my own...

[This thead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63876/changing-the-timestamp-of-a-symlink) is not a solution for me.

**Edit**:

This is not an answer to the question, but it's a solution for my problem: `touch -h *` updates all symlinks timestamps. Seafile recognizes the change and takes action. Fornunately, it re-checks now using the actual file timestamp and upload only the files that changed.

**Edit2**:

The solution using `stat` works: `stat -c "%Y"`. Thanks to [steve](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/104877/steve).

Comment: That works @steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` will give the timestamp of the symlink itself.

So an approach such as below would work

```
[[ $(stat -c '%Y' b) -lt $(stat -c '%Y' a) ]] && touch .......
```